# Can't understand why in Devexpress List Bound example they used CollectionBase class and IEditableObject

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm wondering why in List Bound demo of devexpress example they chose to create custom collection class for use as data-source list like:

```
public class CustomEventList : CollectionBase, IBindingList { ... }
```

And the IEditableObject on the custom object like:

```
public class CustomEvent : IEditableObject { ... }
```

Are there any advantage to this over simply creating BindingList straight away which also works ? On what use-cases, if any, should I use this configuration ?

Also after some research I've found out that CollectionBase class is outdated so now I'm even more confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather old demo coming from .NET 1 where BindingList was not available.  That is the reason, simple as it is :)

Comment: Wow, they should really update their demos. Thank you!